# Links to sections in DT in rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, dt

I want to use DT and inside DT I want to link to sections of the rmarkdown document. I tried the below code but it does not work. How to make proper links to sections in DT in rmarkdown?

````
---
title: "Test links to sections in DT"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo=FALSE)
```

## DT

How to make links work in DT in rmarkdown?

```{r echo=FALSE}
library(DT)
testDF <- data.frame(text=paste0("Section", 1:5), 
                     linksTest1=paste0("[", "Section", 1:5, "]", "(#Section", 1:5, ")"))
datatable(testDF, rownames=FALSE, escape=FALSE)
```

## Section 1 {#Section1}

Section 1

## Section 2 {#Section2}

Section 2

## Section 3 {#Section3}

Section 3

## Section 4 {#Section4}

Section 4

## Section 5 {#Section5}

Section 5
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the normal HTML hyperlink tag, not markdown:

```
library(DT)
testDF <- data.frame(text=paste0("Section", 1:5), 
                     linksTest1=paste0("<a href=#Section", 1:5, ">Section", 1:5, "</a>"))
datatable(testDF, rownames=FALSE, escape=FALSE)
```